# In a $C^*$-algebra, does $b^*a^*ab = 0$ for all $b$ imply $a = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

If an element $a$ of a $C^*$-algebra $A$ satisfies
$$(\forall b ∈ A)(b^*a^*ab = 0),
$$ does it follow that $a = 0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put $b=a^\ast$, we get $0=\|aa^\ast aa^\ast\|
=\|(aa^\ast)^\ast(aa^\ast)\|
=\|aa^\ast\|^2
=\|a\|^4$. Therefore $\|a\|=0$ and $a=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The assumption implies that $ab=0$ for every $b.$ In particular we can take $b=e$ if the algebra contains a unit, or $b=a^*.$ In both cases we obtain $a=0.$